# Могу ли я использовать слово Android в своём приложении Google Play?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Читал про [Случай с тетрисом](https://habrahabr.ru/post/231009/), и сложился такой вопрос: Могу ли я использовать слово Android в названии моего приложения в Google Play?

Comment: Думаю, все зависит от того, как именно его использовать. Если это что то вида "уничтожитель андроида" или "оптимизатор андроида", то не стоит. 

С другой стороны, если приложение уже в google play, то и так понятно, что оно для андроида.

Вывод: каких то существенных причин на включение слова андроид в названия приложения  я не вижу (ну кроме случая, когда [андроид - это человекообразный робот](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4))

Comment: вот есть [Brand Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/brand.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать слово **Android** можно, но только в определенном контексте, например:

> Медиаплеер для Android

- Когда бренд Android упоминается впервые, рядом с ним должен быть
  надстрочный символ товарного знака: ™.
- Использование названия Android в материалах должно сопровождаться
  следующей ссылкой:
- Android является товарным знаком компании Google Inc. Слово Android
  всегда должно быть написано с заглавной буквы и не должно
  использоваться во множественном числе или в притяжательном падеже.

Подробнее - [Читать на офф сайте](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/brand-guidelines)